# Trigger not getting tripped when it should be

Tags: c#, wpf

I have developed an animation for some software i am working that dynamically skews two objects to their respective boundaries and then back again once tripped. The problem i have having is that the script that should be tripping isn't getting executed and i am unable to figure out as to why.

**Please Note: The _fg and _bg values are defined at the top of the class.**

```
public static void Grass(Canvas canvas, int boundry)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    foreach (FrameworkElement element in canvas.Children)
    {
        var elementName = Regex.Split(element.Name, "_");
        if (elementName[0] == "grass")
        {
            switch (elementName[1])
            {
                case "foreground":
                    _fgGrassDrn = (_fgGrassPos == 0 && _fgGrassHbd == 0) ? random.Next(0, 2) : _fgGrassDrn;
                    _fgGrassPos = (_fgGrassDrn == 0) ? _fgGrassPos + 1 : _fgGrassPos - 1;
                    _fgGrassBnd = (_fgGrassDrn == 0) ? boundry : -boundry;
                    if (_fgGrassBnd == boundry) // this is the tripwire code.
                    {
                        _fgGrassHbd = 1;
                        _fgGrassDrn = (_fgGrassDrn == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                    element.RenderTransform = new SkewTransform(_fgGrassPos, 0);
                    break;
                case "background":
                    _bgGrassDrn = (_bgGrassPos == 0 && _bgGrassHbd == 0) ? random.Next(0, 2) : _bgGrassDrn;
                    _bgGrassPos = (_bgGrassDrn == 0) ? _bgGrassPos + 1 : _bgGrassPos - 1;
                    _bgGrassBnd = (_bgGrassDrn == 0) ? boundry : -boundry;
                    if (_bgGrassBnd == boundry) // this is the tripwire code.
                    {
                        _bgGrassHbd = 1;
                        _bgGrassDrn = (_bgGrassDrn == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                    element.RenderTransform = new SkewTransform(_bgGrassPos, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling i am missing something very obvious but i have only been programming in c# for around 5 days, so excuse me :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem, it was indeed a silly mistake of mine. I was comparing the Methods parameter **boundary** which doesn't take in to account the direction of the Grass making it always positive.

```
if (_fgGrassBnd == _fgGrassPos) {}
if (_bgGrassBnd == _bgGrassPos) {}
```

**_fgGrassBnd** and **_bgGrassBnd** are the calculated boundaries (positive for left, negative for right) which makes this Animation work as intended.